# access the error block in ajax request even the reponse is 200 ok

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, jquery

i am doing dross domain request from ajax. the request seems to be ok and it is hiting database successfuly and returning 200 ok response but in client side still it is going in failure block.
this is my code.

```
validate($(".confpassword").val(),$("#psw").val());
    var firstname = $("#firstname").val();
    var lastname = $("#lastname").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#psw").val();
    var birthday = $("#birthday").val();

    var sendInfo = {
        firstname: firstname,
        lastname: lastname,
        email: email,
        password: password,
        birthday: birthday
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:3001/users/create',
        data: JSON.sendInfo,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

        success: function (data) {
                alert('success.............');
        },
        error: function(){
             alert('failure............');
        }
    });
```

if somebody knows please help me

this is my server side response in ruby:

```
def create
  @user=User.create(:birthday=> params[:birthday],:email=> params[:email],:firstname=> params[:firstname], :lastname=> params[:lastname],:password=>params[:password])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.json { render :json => @user,:status=>200}
    else
      format.json { render :json => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity}
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since browser doesnot allow cross-domain server calls we can do that by configuring apache as a proxy to interact with target server

Here is the solution. 
Add a "Location" tag in http.conf file of local apache server. Then your server will act as proxy and redirect your calls to target server.

Example:

ProxyPass abc dot come
    ProxyPassReverse abc dot com

All calls to <> will be redirected to abc dot com

Hope this would be helpful to you.

Comment: <Location /api/>
    ProxyPass abc.com
    ProxyPassReverse abc.com
</Location>

Comment: but i am using rails (webrick) service

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how JSON.sendInfo works, but in JSONP you need to return a callback from the url and pass it back into the response, like this:

`format.jsonp { render json: results, callback: params[:callback]}`

Comment: but we cant use jsonp with post request. I have tried that already